# Is `return` alone equivalent to `return(None)` in Python 3.8?

Tags: python-3.x, return, return-value, return-type, nonetype

I just saw the following Python code, and I'm a bit confused by the first `return`. Does it return `None` by default? Is it equivalent to `return(None)`? If the first `return` is executed, will the function `inner()` automatically end there and the second `return` be left alone?

```
def smart_check(f):
    def inner(a,b):
        if b==0:
            print("illegit: b =", b)
            return   # the first return
        return(f(a,b))
    return(inner)

@smart_check
def divide(a,b):
    return(a/b)
```

Comment: A lone `return` will exit the function and return a `None` value.

Comment: Aside: the return keyword is not a function call or operator. The extra parenthesis are superfluous and usually not included. They may also be confused with/hide when the goal is to return a tuple.

Comment: @pyOliv Thank you! That's clarifying! BTW, is there a way to exit the function without returning anything?

Comment: @user2864740 I think the parentheses are necessary in Python 3

Comment: Parenthesis are _not_ required for return in any version. Parenthesis were made mandatory for print vs Python 2 (as print lost its keyword / special statement status).

Comment: Function _always_ return _a value_ if they terminate without raising an error (or otherwise terminating Python). None is _a value_ which denotes “nothing”. This is required for “x = f()”, eg., to guarantee _a value_ will be assigned to “x”, should the call to “f” finish normally. Some languages separate subroutines and function: Python does not.

Comment: @user2864740 oh thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it return None by default? Is it equivalent to return(None)

Yes, see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement): If an expression list is present, it is evaluated, **else None is
substituted**.

> If the first return is executed, will the function inner()
>   automatically end there and the second return be left alone?

Yes

---

If you don't want to return anything you can even drop the return statement completely:

```
 def smart_check(f):
    def inner(a,b):
        if b != 0:
            return f(a,b)
        print("illegit: b =", b)
    return(inner)
```

As print doesn't return anything you could even rewrite this function as

```
def smart_check(f):
   def inner(a,b):
       return f(a,b) if b!=0 else print("illegit: b =", b)
   return(inner)
```